# How to fix "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment"

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and I'm having an annoying problem that I don't know how to deal with. I am trying to create an application that uses two fragments. But when you open the application, it crumbles.
I've tried commenting out parts of code that I thought might be contributing to it but I believe that the problem has something to do with my xml, but I am not very familiar with them yet.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private String ADBPATH;
    MyIO myIO = new MyIO();
    RunCmd runCmd = new RunCmd();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        ADBPATH = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
        firstStart();
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (!runCmd.runCMD("getprop service.adb.tcp.port").equals("-1")) {
            runCmd.runCMD("su -c setprop service.adb.tcp.port -1 && stop adbd && start adbd && "
                    + ADBPATH + "/arnold kill-server");
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void firstStart() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("share", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isFirstRun = pref.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("share", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        if (isFirstRun) {
            editor.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
            editor.apply();
            myIO.copy(MainActivity.this, "arnold");
            myIO.copy(MainActivity.this, "arnold.bin");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.installFragment2) {

        } else if (id == R.id.screenFragment2) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:saveEnabled="true"
        android:scrollY="1dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:insetForeground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Log

```
2022-12-25 16:03:38.873 9611-9611/com.buratinoapps.aweartool E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.buratinoapps.aweartool, PID: 9611
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.buratinoapps.aweartool/com.buratinoapps.aweartool.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.buratinoapps.aweartool:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #23 in com.buratinoapps.aweartool:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3685)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3842)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2252)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.buratinoapps.aweartool:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #23 in com.buratinoapps.aweartool:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.buratinoapps.aweartool:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.buratinoapps.aweartool.InstallFragment cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:613)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:184)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:212)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:80)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:30)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:823)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:521)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:482)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:447)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:429)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:226)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2949)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:278)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
2022-12-25 16:03:38.874 9611-9611/com.buratinoapps.aweartool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.buratinoapps.aweartool.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8054)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8034)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1341)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3666)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3842)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2252)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
2022-12-25 16:03:38.928 9611-9611/com.buratinoapps.aweartool I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9611 SIG: 9
```

Comment: There is no Tag fragment in xml, if you want to add a fragment to your Activity, add FrameLayout tag instead of fragment